# Developing an app based on Webpage, without web developer's assistance

Tags: android, ios, web-deployment

Here is the scenario:

I am going to be developing an app, both IOS and Android, for a client based on features that they already have in a webpage. The information has to match up i.e. user accounts and uploaded images. The company doesn't necessarily want to get the web developer involved.

a) Is this even possible? (I know if it is, it will be a bit hacky)
b) If it is possible, what issues should I be expecting (I know there could be millions, but just saying if someone has done this before)

Answer (score 0):

a ) Well, Its possible. There are frameworks ([ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) , [react framework](https://facebook.github.io/react/index.html)) that are created for consistent UX-UI across platforms. They are quite good for many use-cases. So, if your website is developed with such a framework you can expect a decent output. But if you had developed the website with other responsive frameworks - like boostrap or similar, there will  be differences in UX though not much in UI when ported to Mobile.

b) Issues :

- Webview component, on which your app relies heavily should also be up-to date on end-users device. Otherwise, you may see some inconsistencies. Remember, webview is not browser. Its a light weight webengine.
- Web components do not really mimic the latest UX feel of Android OS. Its difficult to achieve the smoothness of native UI component from web component.
- If user tries to do drag gesture inside your webview, then other parts of UI might not be in sync - like action bar or other native components. If you run in fullscreen mode, then margins for the website are generally seen empty in boundary cases.

There might be other issues, like if you have to persist user preferences, then you need to propagate data between html ( webview ) and java. This can be tedious.

App life-cycle may also get effected - say, if you are playing a video - suddenly user switches to another app - how do you plan to handle this?

Use cases can extend like this. Try to concentrate only on your specific requirement and conclude on a best solution possible.